# Why does %s accepts Integer type variable and %d gives an error for a String variable

Tags: python

```
enter code here
my_name="vamsi"
my_age=20
my_height=74
my_weight=180
my_eyes="Blue"
my_teeth="White"
my_hair="Brown"

print "Let's talk about %s" % my_name
print "He's %s inches tall" % my_height # This works fine
print "He's %d pounds heavy"%my_weight
print "He's got %d eyes and %s hair"%(my_eyes,my_hair) #This gives error asking for an integer
```

In the above code snippet, The %s is accepting the Integer and is printing the exact value of the Integer. But %d does not do it for a String and instead saying an error `number is required ,not str`.

ps: This Question is not duplicate , It may be using old python as prescribed in http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex5.html and I have done my work by searching online before asking the question, posted code and errors at the time of asking !

Comment: it is by design - if you don't like it write a PEP and suggest a change to the language. Also it is better now to use the `.format` method.

Comment: Probably because you can always cast an integer to string, but not always the other way round.

Comment: @Bart : Haha ,I'm just starting this python! But I would probably make a suggestion though in future

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh How can you talk about future, when you're living in the past, using 3.5 years old Python?

Comment: @OlehPrypin: Would you like him to instead use a programming language that hasn't been invented yet?

Comment: It doesn't work any better than `int(my_eyes)` would.

Comment: Such weird closing reasons. It's a genuine question and misunderstanding from a beginner, why close?

Comment: The search/Google-fu for Python is often to read the (official) documentation. But since there is so much of it, it may be hard to find it inside the documentation. But, as per my answer, it is there.

Comment: Note that StackOverflow isn't really a beginners forum, though. If you are a Python beginner, you may want to ask at the [Python tutor mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor).

Comment: @Evert: No one ever said that StackOverflow is not for beginners .But they are frowned upon cause, they will be generally asking duplicate questions, or questions without searching online, or asking their homework. But I'm not not new to this site and have complied to all the rules for posting a question on SO.

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh Its been a while you have asked your question. So, are you now perfect in python programming?

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `s` formatter, any object is implicitly converted to a string by using the `str()`. Something similar exists for the `r` formatter, which will call `repr()` on the object.

These rules are not defined for, for example, an integer: the `d` formatter does not imply a call to `int()`, since this is not always defined (`int("hello")` will raise a `ValueError`, for example). See also Bart's comment.

You can find this in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) (second table).

This also works nicely when, for example, one uses the `logging` module, where you can simply tell the formatting string to use "%s", supply the object you're interested in for logging, and something sensible (well, hopefully) will show up; no chance of an Exception, so your code will log whatever you're interested in without crashing.

People mentioned the `format` method to strings. The default there (the empty `{}` inside the string) depends on the used object: it will use `d` formatting for an integer, `s` for a string, and `g` for a floating point. See the [tables in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), which are listed for each type.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is for strings, `%d` is for digits

Instead you could try using `.format()`, how about this:

```
my_name = 'vamsi'
my_height = 74
my_eyes = 'Blue'
my_hair = 'Brown'

print 'Let\'s talk about {}'.format(my_name)
print 'He\'s {} inches tall'.format(my_height)
print 'He\'s got {eyes} eyes and {hair} hair'.format(eyes=my_eyes, hair=my_hair)
```

Now you can swap variables without having to change the placeholders. The last line of code may seem a little verbose but it can add to the readability.